# count items and showing them as well

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write a query that returns a list of boxes containing the items I selected and show them ordered by the content I've selected. If I select Item1, Item2 and Item3, the result I'd like to see is:

```
BoxA, 3 , Item1
BoxA, 3 , Item2
BoxA, 3 , Item3
BoxB, 2 , Item2
BoxB, 2 , Item3
```

Which means that BoxA has 3 of the items I selected and the items are Item1,Item2,Item3.
I can't find a way to do a single query. All I can do is (Note that I use ids instead of item names, just for simplicity.To add the item names is easy.):

```
 SELECT b.name,count(*) cnt, ib.i_id 
 FROM boxes b, items_boxes ib 
 WHERE b.id=ib.b_id and ib.i_id in (1,2,3,4) 
 GROUP BY b.id 
 ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

This query return the Box names and the count of item in them, while the item (or i_id) is just the first.
How do I obtain what I need? should I use two select?

sqlFiddle: [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d925/2)

Comment: please add the tables and some data. May be in http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Can you post what your query is returning as to what is required..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the counting as a separate sub-query, and join that to your results.

```
SELECT
  b.name,
  ibc.cnt,
  ib.i_id
FROM
  boxes         b
INNER JOIN
  items_boxes   ib
    ON b.id = ib.b_id
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT b_id, COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM items_boxes
   WHERE i_id IN (1,2,3,4)
GROUP BY b_id
)
  ibc
    ON b.id = ibc.b_id
WHERE
  ib.i_id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

To account for boxes with no items, just turn the `INNER JOIN`s in to `LEFT JOIN`s.

**EDIT :**

Added a SQL Fiddle example of the above code.  Table names are slightly different in the SQL Fiddle, so the SQL has been modified there to reflect that.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d925/7

Comment: I suppose this is the only way to do that. Is it the optimal? I have 400000 boxes and 13000 items, but the boxes should have max 20 items.

Comment: @mobinoob - As always, it depends.  Will you always be returning all 400k boxes, or just a sub-set?  Will you be using the results in another query, or in an application where you could do the scan-and-count there?  Other RDBMS allow other constructs such as `COUNT(ib.i_id) OVER (PARTITION BY ib.b_id) AS cnt` instead of using the sub-query, but MySQL doesn't support that yet.  If it's what you need, it's what you need - Your only options appear to be to look at indexes to optimise the query, or to have another table with these results pre-calculated.